# Momentjs date value convert into datetime format

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have used moment js in date & time formatting, to be in a readable and string(month) manner. Now I am trying to get the same original formate here:

My original value: `2019-04-23T19:17:48.000Z`

After moment: 
`moment('2019-04-23T19:17:48.000Z').format('dddd Do YYYY, h:mm:ss')`

output: 
`Wednesday 24th 2019, 12:47:48`

now all I need my original value back by using the `output` here.

Any lead appreciates for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

With only the data you're providing as an output of `Wednesday 24th 2019, 12:47:48 am` you can't really get back to your original value. If it were a valid date, there's not a month. You'd need logic to determine what 24ths of each month in 2019 are a Wednesday.

After some testing - there's a few things you need in order to get this string back into a date that Moment can recognize

```
moment('2019-04-23T19:17:48.000Z').format('dddd MMMM D YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
moment('Tuesday April 23 2019, 7:17:48 pm').format()
```

1. You have to have the month, otherwise it thinks its an invalid date. That can be the string of the month or just the number `4` in this case.
2. Moment won't take the `rd` from `23rd` otherwise it's an invalid date.

You can either use some string transformations to get it back into a useable date object or add on a little extra data like the month and when you go to use that date format,

```
"Tuesday April 23 2019, 7:17:48 pm".replace('April ', '')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are the best solution for the date formate under UTC/GMT:

```
let dateTime = new Date("2015-09-30T19:54:21.000Z");
dateTime = moment(dateTime).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
moment(moment(dateTime).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")).format();
```

**o/p => "2015-09-30T14:24:21+05:30"**

```
moment("2015-09-30T14:24:21+05:30").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

**o/p => "2015-09-30 14:24:21"**

```
moment.tz('2015-09-30 14:24:21', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', 'UTC').format()
```

**final o/p => "2015-09-30T14:24:21Z"**

Comment: Not sure how this relates to the question!

Comment: @AnupamMaurya You have no idea who downvoted. It is actually highly likely that it was *not* phuzi.

Comment: As @Ajean stated, it wasn't necessarily me that down-voted the answer. For the avoidance of doubt though, it was. The question refers to parsing of a date string in a specific format ('dddd MMMM D YYYY, h:mm:ss a') which hasn't even been mentioned in this answer. I appreciate that you asked the question, but the answer doesn't answer the question as stated.

Comment: @phuzi got your point & updated the `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss a)` to  `(YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)` , basically removed AM/PM parameter(now smile!). But the thing is to understand the concept only here. *not AM/PM stuff*. Question is updated now. .

Comment: I'd agree but the questions on SO are meant to be fairly specific, as in, you have a specific problem. As stated, your question doesn't even include the month in the string you want to parse. The answer still doesn't apply, and would unlikely be helpful to someone else with the same/similar issue.